# Segmentation fault when calling function from shared version of library

Tags: c++, c, dll, callback

I have an application that needs to set the logging callback that will be used by a library to report information. I originally compiled my library statically, but now I need to use it as a dll. When my application calls a function to test a failure condition, the library is supposed to log the reason the function failed using the callback. This works without issue when linked statically, but causes a segmentation fault when linked dynamically. This happens immediately as the function is called, and I cannot step into the logging callback.

My application is able to call the API functions defined in the dll, it is the dll function that causes the fault as soon as it attempts to call the logging callback. This even happens when I use a stub function built into the library and the application does not try to use a custom callback.

My library is written in C, the application is a C++ GUI using Qt. I use Qt Creator to build my library (MinGW), but my library does not use anything from the Qt libraries.

Here is the definition of my logging callback type:

```
    typedef void __attribute__((cdecl)) LogFn(char const * const fname, unsigned int const line, LogLvl const level, unsigned long long const time, Err const err, char const * const reason);
```

Here is the declaration and example call of my logging function, it is global for the library:

```
    LogFn * DebugLogFn = LogDflt;
    DebugLogFn(LOG_FNAME, __LINE__, LOG_WARN_ENUM, CurTime(), ERR_X_ENUM, "something");
```

LogDflt is the stub function the library uses before the application specifies a custom callback:

```
    void __attribute__((cdecl)) LogDflt(char const * const fname, unsigned int const line, LogLvl const level, unsigned long long const time, Err const err, char const * const reason) {
        // do nothing
    }
```

This works perfectly when I link statically, even when setting the callback to a static function of one of my application's classes.

Also, the application will execute completely normally when linked dynamically, as long as I don't pass bad input to a dll function, since this causes it try to call the log function.

Stack trace:

```
    0   ??              
    1   test_create_destroy Test.c  225 0x40aaec    
    2   Test::run   test.cpp    70  0x40408f    
    3   QThreadPrivate::start(void*)*4      407 0x6b798b92  
    4   msvcrt!_itow_s  C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75551287  
    5   msvcrt!_endthreadex C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75551328  
    6   KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk    C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll        0x75cd337a  
    7   ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain   C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll       0x777d92e2  
    8   ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain   C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll       0x777d92b5  
    9   ??
```

Comment: Can you post some stacktrace? Also how do you register the callback?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not very helpful. Right now, the callback is not being registered since even calling the stub function causes it to crash.